how to remove/hide wordpress menu from admin dashboard for specific users
I'm using this to hide menu items for a specific user. What's the best way to do this for more than one user using the id.
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu_pages_for_user' );
function remove_menu_pages_for_user() {

if (get_current_user_id() == 1) {
    //remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );              //Dashboard
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                 //Posts
    remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );               //Media
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );  //Pages
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );        //Comments
    remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );               //Appearance
    remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );              //Plugins
    remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                //Users
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                //Tools
    remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );      //Settings
}
}

This code works for user 1 but need to add one or 2 additional users.

Use in_array in your if condition ...?

You can do this by getting current user id and then check if that user exsists in array we have created.
so you just need to replace
if (get_current_user_id() == 1) {

with
 $user_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 ); //here you can replace 1,2,3 as per the User ID for which you want to remove menu.
 $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
 if ( in_array( $current_user_id, $user_ids ) ) {

It should works for you.

Perfect. Thank you so much!

You are very welcome.
